# Select value from list based on value in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to select a value from a range of values, based on the number entered in a certain cell. Assume I have the following data available:

```
1   308.331
2   292.363
3   289.582
4   294.610
5   300.468
6   298.427
7   292.433
8   293.646
9   282.613
10  293.143
```

(Note that this data is inside the same excel-sheet.)

If I enter number `10` into cell A1, how can I get to display the value for number 10 `293.143` displayed into A2?

I have been looking at complex if statements but that doesn't seem like the correct way to go. Is there something of a `select from` function available in excel?

Comment: You could certainly search for info on how to use `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `VLOOKUP()` ... https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Assuming the following layout ...

[image]

Put this into cell E1 ...

```
=VLOOKUP(D1, $A$1:$B$10, 2, FALSE)
```

Note the use of the 4th parameter `FALSE` ... that looks for an exact match.